# SQL combine WITH clause and Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

How is it possible to use **declared parameter**, a **WITH clause** and a **cursor** in one Query

```
declare @TOP10 table (Cat Nvarchar(max),SubGUID uniqueidentifier)
declare @Sub uniqueidentifier
declare GUID_Cursor cursor FOR
(select SubGUID from dbo.Sub with(nolock) where year=2016)
;
with [MyTable] as
(
Select SubGUID, color from dbo.Cars with(nolock) where color ='blue'
)


open GUID_Cursor
fetch next from GUID_Cursor into @Sub
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
insert into @TOP10 (Cat,SubGUID)

select color,SubGUID from [MyTable]
where SubGUID=@Sub

fetch next from GUID_Cursor into @Sub

end
close GUID_Cursor
deallocate GUID_Cursor

select * from @TOP10
```

I just cant find a way tu open the cursor after using the **WITH** clause.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: A CTE is just a sub query.  Rewrite it as such and that should help.

Comment: shouldn't be the `with` clause after `declare cursor for`?

Answer (score 4):

Well, aside from the logic of your code (for me - there is no need of cursor here at all), you should just move CTE declaration closer to the place where you're using it.

```
;with [MyTable] as
(
    Select SubGUID, color from dbo.Cars with(nolock) where color ='blue'
)
insert into @TOP10 (Cat,SubGUID)    
select color,SubGUID from [MyTable]
where SubGUID=@Sub
```

But really, all your code could be replaced with:

```
declare @TOP10 table (Cat Nvarchar(max),SubGUID uniqueidentifier)

insert into @TOP10 (Cat,SubGUID)
select color,SubGUID 
from dbo.Cars with(nolock) 
where 
    color ='blue'
    and SubGUID in (select SubGUID from dbo.Sub with(nolock) where year=2016)

select * from @TOP10
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @AndyKorneyev, but for the sake of experiment:

```
declare @crTest CURSOR,
        @name VARCHAR(1000),
        @type VARCHAR(1000)

set @crTest = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    WITH cteObjs AS (
        SELECT TOP 10 NAME, type
        FROM sys.objects o
        )
    select name, type
    from cteObjs


OPEN @crTest

FETCH NEXT FROM @crTest
INTO @name, @type

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @name
    PRINT @type

    FETCH NEXT FROM @crTest
    INTO @name, @type
END

CLOSE @crTest
DEALLOCATE @crTest
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to repeat above snippets but be aware that `WITH` clause result set must be processed directly at it's end.

Unlike your @tableVar, the scope of the result set that is returned by cte is not valid within complete batch and therefore must be **followed by SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement**.
(for details and examples see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx or follow one of the other answers).

e. g.

```
    --> declare var: 
    declare @tableVar table (colOne int, colTwo nvarchar(30)
    );

    --> use cte: 
    with preOne as(select carId, color from pcUser with (nolock)
    )
    --> directly followed by insert:
    insert into @tableVar(userId, logInName)
      select colOne, colTwo from @tableVar;

    --> use var in cursor or anywhere else in the batch
```

Though I'm not exactly sure what you aim at, perhaps a short join could do the trick here:

```
select a.[SubGUID]
from [dbo].[Sub] as a with (nolock) 
    inner join [dbo].[Cars] as b with (nolock) on a.[SubGUID] = b.[SubGUID]
where a.[year] = 2016 and b.[color] = 'blue';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used temp tabeles like #TOP10. Which I droped after the query. As soon as I got rid of the `with [MyTable] as` part I had no more problems with the parameters.

Thank you all lot.